# How to add to PHP.ini on Azure Web Services?

Tags: php, azure, initialization, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.drupal.org/node/2481341

The second step says:

2. On global PHP level add `curl.cainfo = [enter your path]\cacert.pem` to your `php.ini`.

How would I add this line to my current `php.ini` file in my Azure App Services?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Follow these steps in order to change PHP_INI_SYSTEM configuration settings-

1. Add an App Setting to your Web App with the key PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR and value d:\home\site\ini
2. Create an settings.ini file using Kudu Console (http://.scm.azurewebsite.net) in the d:\home\site\ini directory.
3. Add configuration settings to the settings.ini file using the same syntax you would use in a php.ini file. For example, if you wanted to point the curl.cainfo setting to a *.crt file and set 'wincache.maxfilesize' setting to 512K, your settings.ini file would contain this text:

> curl.cainfo="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
>
> wincache.maxfilesize=512

4. Restart your Web App to load the changes.

You can refer to the standard document provided by Microsoft from here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations

Comment: Note: It might be obvious for some, but if you're using a Linux container the path must be `/home/site/ini` instead of `d:\home\site\ini`

Answer (score 7):

For Linux, the correct value of `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` should be `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d:/home/site/ini` otherwise a lot of default `.ini` files won't be loaded.

Comment: This needs an upvote. From official [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux#customize-php_ini_system-directives)