# Azure Web App: how to increase PHP memory limit for the deployment process? Nothing works

Tags: php, laravel, azure

We are trying to deploy a Laravel app to Azure.

Everything went fine until the composer started. At some point it breaks down saying that all the memory was exhausted - clearly, it looks like the PHP memory limit is ~2MB, which is obviously too little.

The problem is that we can't increase this limit in any way - we used an ini file added to the storage ([method described here](https://azureossd.github.io/2019/01/29/azure-app-service-linux-update-php-settings/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux)) and we used adding directives to .htaccess (also [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux)), but none of those worked.

To make it even more strange when we navigate to the site and execute a small php file with echo <?php phpinfo();> in it it shows the PHP memory limit to be 128M - way less than what we set in the ini file, but way more than what the error reports.
That would indicate that the environment composer runs in is different from the environment the site actually runs in.

What gives? Anyone had this problem?

```
remote: Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
remote: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /tmp/8d8df2faa270e0a/vendor/composer/autoload_static.php on line 1724
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out our problem had two solutions:

- app apparently ignoring the additional .ini file created inside the /home directory in Azure ([as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601176/ddg#39601463)) -> this is solved by simply restarting the app inside Azure Portal (for Linux users this is not intuitive),
- composer running out of memory -> this was solved by setting the environment variable COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT for the app inside Azure Portal to -1 (this is accomplished by going to your app in Azure Portal, then "Configuration" and editing or adding this value in "Application settings" tab or using [`az webapp config appsettings` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest)).

Answer (score 1):

The difference you notice is that Azure App Services run different configuration settings for CLI and web.

In order to increase memory you can modify the app service parameters in the portal where you specify PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR (as mentioned in [How to add PHP.ini on Azure App Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601176/ddg#39601463)).

An other way is to modify your composer.json file where you modify the script with `php -dmemory_limit=512M` so it will use the memory you specify in your artisan command.

If all that fails, and this is the preferred way, is to build and run all the things locally or in a CI/CD environment and create a zip file of your whole application. Use the Azure CLI to push and deploy that zip onto your App Service.

Comment: The thing is we added an ini file and added it to scan dirs as described, but it seems to have no effect. Interestingly, in the php-info dump we can do over the web we can see the PHP has read our additional file, but the memory limit stays at 128M anyway... :(

Comment: OK, I now know why .ini directory had no effect - I did not know in Azure changing the ini files is not enough and I was not restarting the app from the Azure Portal. Now I did it and in the execution (web) environment the memory limit went up. But this indeed did not affect the deployment environment.

Comment: OK, what solved the problem was setting the environment variable to COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT to -1 using Azure Portal.